# Android send Camera Preview from Activity to Fragment TextureView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-camera

There is a `TextureView` in my `Fragment` and Fragment must be re-inflate a Layout. I using `Camera` API in `Activity` (PS: Camera API must be call in Activity), and I can use `SurfaceTexture` to get Camera Preview.

Question how to make TextureView can get Camera preview. I tired many solutions but all of them got null object reference.

```
public class MyFragment extends PresentationFragment{
    private TextureView textureView;
    private TextView textView;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, @Nullable ViewGroup contatiner, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.external_display, contatiner, false);
        textureView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        textView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.test_text);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

In Activity:

```
private MyFragment myFragment;
private TextureView textureView;
private SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture;
```

In onCreate:

```
myFragment =(myFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.external_display);
View view = myFragment.getView();
textureView = view.findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
surfaceTexture = textureView.getSurfaceTexture();
```

getView() null object reference.

Comment: Can you add your code snippet here that you have tried...

Comment: I add some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the Activity lifecycle for you. The fragment views are not available in onCreate. Luckily, this should not be a problem: it's not correct to initialise the camera before onRestore.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I call camera in onResume(), I move getView() to onResume which still can not get object reference:(

Comment: How do you load your fragment or fragments?

Comment: I found problem, when I call Fragment TextureView from Activity, onCreateView() has not been called. so I create a listener when onCreateView() finish, activity will know. Thank you for your help.